# Using ismember function to find multiple locations. (Matlab)

Tags: arrays, matlab, vector, find

This question is about the Matlab function `ismember` or alternative method

I have a vector X which contains multiple occurrences of Y, i would like to know the rows that Y appears in, all of them not just one. This vector will be much larger in my code so any recommendations on efficiency/time saving would be hugely appreciated.

My code reads:

> X = [1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1]'
>
> Y=0
>
> [~,indx]=ismember(Y,X,'rows')

The output I get is:

> indx =
>
> ```
>  8
> ```

Ideally I would like the output to be something along the lines of this:

> indx =
>
> [3 6 8]

Is it possible to get this solution with `ismember` or should I be looking at something like the `find` function?

As always thank you very much for your time and help.

Comment: use `find`, or consider [logical indexing](http://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/Matrix-Indexing-in-MATLAB/matrix.html) depending on your use of `indx`.

Comment: Thanks Shai, Ill look into both your suggestions.

Comment: `find` does exactly what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the indices of all matching elements, you can use the [find](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/find.html) function. This does exactly what you decribe.

As [Shai also mentioned in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17446226/using-ismember-function-to-for-multiple-locations-matlab#comment25344966_17446226), logical indexing is another potential solution to your problem, which may be *a lot* more efficient depending on what you plan to do later on. It is best to familiarize yourself with both methods.

Comment: Thanks Marc and Shai, the find function seems to be the way to go.